# Would wiping a partition and breaking grub then reflashing off a live USB be safe?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, budgie

I currently have a dual boot Ubuntu budgie install with windows, but the windows install broke when resizing partitions and I can't boot it. I want to:

Remove the windows partition 
Plug in a USB with Ubuntu (stock) on
Reflash the budgie and now free windows partition with stock ubuntu

Would this break anything? Apparently resizing budgie breaks stuff and it's been quite glitchy on me regarding changing desktop fonts so I want to try stock Ubuntu.

Comment: No.  It won't break anything any further than it's already broken (your Windows install is broken you say and removing it wouldn't further break it).

Comment: I would resize your partitions first from a live usb to what you want, and then install.  Backup everything you want to keep before hand.